# Redirecting audio / broadcasting audio help

Tags: audio

Okay so I have an interesting problem that I have been having a lot of trouble solving.  I am trying to broadcast StarCraft 2 games to Justin TV via Dyyno Universal Broadcaster.  I can either have it broadcast the game audio and the audio of my party from teamspeak without my voice, or continuously broadcast my microphone without any other audio.

Currently I have solved the problem by using a headset and listening to my own microphone, so my mic is pumped through my computer's audio which Dyyno picks up on so I can broadcast my mic continuously, the game audio and my party on teamspeak.

This is the exact thing I need to do but I hate listening to myself, so is there a better way to do this?  or somehow create an audio device that I can pump everything I want to broadcast through and then have Dyyno listen to that and then I can just listen to the game and my party and not myself??

I know this is probably tldr but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into Soundflower by Cycling '74

http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/

It allows you to control all the audio ins and outs and where they go, internally.  The link seems to be unreachable ATM and I don't know why, but I think that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That would, but I need a solution for Windows.  SoundFlower is Mac Only I believe.

Comment: ah!  apologies.  what about this program? http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am revisiting this because I found a new program that works beautifully for this.  If anyone is having the issues I was having above, you need to check out XSplit.  It is a wonderful piece of software.